# Error migrating server Openstack host different than nova server

Tags: migration, openstack, virsh

A migration of an instance failed. Now in nova, the host is in host A while in virsh the running instance is in  host B.

How can I set in nova, because openstack is showing in error state.

Comment: If you shared more details what went wrong people might be able to help. Why did the migration fail and at which point? Is host A still up? The simplest way would be to migrate it back so the database is up to data again. Or if host A is (currently) not available you could edit the database entries as a last resort. But only consider that if you really know what you're doing.